# Cannot pass successfully login session cookies into a class method using Python

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I have a webpage where I need to login to web scrape product price

So I have a class with my parsing method which I call after my successful login.

But I get only the page without the price so I get NoneType object is not Subscriptable

```
class Parser(object):
    ses = requests.Session()

    def parse(self, urls):
        url = urls[1]

        try:
            r = self.ses.get(url)
            sleep(3)
            if r.status_code == 200:
            
                Myhtml = r.text

                soup = BeautifulSoup(Myhtml, 'html.parser')
                print('Get Soup..')
                price = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'price'})
                availability = soup.select_one('div.availability > span')['class'][0]

                #Checking Conditions                    

                data = [urls[0], price_text, availability_text]

                return data

            else:
                print(r.status_code.text)

        except TypeError as e:
            print(e)
            return []
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
            return []
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e)
            return []
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return []

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('Starting..')

    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe')

    browser.get('https://www.acihellas.gr/login')

    #LOGIN PROCESS Passing Username and Password into form

    s = requests.Session()

    parser = Parser()
    parser.ses = s

    browser.quit()


    for link in web_links:
        parser.parse(link)

    #export to csv
```

I dont know if it is useful info but at the point of

```
r = self.ses.get(url)
```

ses has two cookies after that r has one cookie

What I doing wrong here? I tried the way of

```
 cookies = browser.get_cookies()
    for cookie in cookies:
        s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
```

But again the same result
How to keep the authentication cookie for each url I want to parse?

Comment: Could you please post the URL

Comment: This is the login url https://www.acihellas.gr/login

Comment: so your problem is that you can't login successfully?

Comment: The problem is that I login successfully, but in the request of url r = self.ses.get(url) is not using the cookie of authenticated login but the initial cookie so as a result I get nothing